# Button.setVisibility crashed Android Application

Tags: java, android, xml

I have encountered an error in my Android application. When I call setVisible() on pauseB, the application crashes due to pauseB being initialized to null. It's odd because calling setVisible() on startB works just fine. Here is the relevant code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
...imports...

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static boolean toggle=false;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void beginGame(View v)
{
    Button startB= (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.startButton);
    startB.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    Button pauseB = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.pauseButton);
    pauseB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    rest of method...
}

rest of code...
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.placemultiplebuttons_android_examples.com.MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Start!"
        android:onClick="beginGame" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pauseButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/startButton"
        android:text="Pause"
        android:onClick="pauseGame" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the exception given by AndroidStudio:

**Exception**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: com.example.jackson.myfirstapp, PID: 2285
                                                                              java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
                                                                                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                                  at com.example.jackson.myfirstapp.MainActivity.beginGame(MainActivity.java:29)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                                                                                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
                                                                                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Restating the problem, the error happens on the line

```
pauseB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

For the life of me I cannot figure it out. Any help here is appreciated as I am an Android novice. Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: There is no `pauseGame(View v){}` in your code sample.

Comment: Though he does not provide `pauseGame` method in code (that would give different error), I think it's a good question and one of general mistakes by Android beginners. Hardly understand why `-3` votes on it. too harsh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you got the crash is,

1. Click `startButton` executes `beginGame` method.
2. The `beginGame` method, `v` argument has `startButton` Button View.
3. so your `Button pauseB = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.pauseButton);` points `R.id.pauseButton` inside of `startButton` Button View.
4. Crash occurred, because the `startButton` does not contain `pauseButton`. The `pauseButton` View is in `R.layout.activity_main` of Activity not `startButton` View.

To fix this, declare button variables globally, and define them in `onCreate` after the `setContentView`.

```
Button startB = null;
Button pauseB = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    startB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
    pauseB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pauseButton);
}

public void beginGame(View v)
{
    startB.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    pauseB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    // rest of method...
}
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you for the prompt and effective response. This fixed it, case closed!

Comment: @JacksonHoagland // happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `v.findViewById(...)` try `findViewById(...)` alone.